# Why this query is returning empty rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, str-to-date

I have data in this format

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `historical_data` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_day` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevclose_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `symbol_name` (`symbol_name`,`current_day`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `historical_data` (`symbol_name`, `current_day`, `open_val`, `high_val`, `low_val`, `close_val`, `last_val`, `prevclose_val`) VALUES
    ('IBWSL', '10-DEC-2015', '9.35', '9.8', '9', '9.45', '9.6', '9.5'),
    ('ICICIBANK', '10-DEC-2015', '260.85', '261.9', '256', '258.95', '258.65', '259.45'),
    ('ICIL', '10-DEC-2015', '981', '1004.2', '981', '989.7', '992', '988.45'),
    ('ICNX100', '10-DEC-2015', '86.8', '87.99', '86.8', '87', '87', '82.5'),
    ('ICRA', '10-DEC-2015', '4175', '4280', '4144', '4211.4', '4279.95', '4175.3'),
    ('ZYDUSWELL', '14-DEC-2015', '815.75', '815.75', '785.25', '810.7', '810.5', '803.1'),
    ('ZYLOG', '14-DEC-2015', '2.9', '2.95', '2.85', '2.95', '2.95', '2.19');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `historical_data` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

I have written the query this way

```
select * from (
    select 
      symbol_name , 
      (prevclose_val-close_val) as losers,
      'daily' as `type` 
    from
      historical_data
    where
      current_day >= STR_TO_DATE('14-DEC-2015', '%d-%MMM-%Y')
    order by losers asc limit 10 
) as sub_daily
```

This is my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4819

Comment: don't you need `STR_TO_DATE()` on `current_day` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **STR_TO_DATE()** function both side because you had stored date as varchar column in database.

You can also use **DATE** as DATATYPE to remove this type of date conversion in all queries

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT symbol_name , (prevclose_val-close_val) AS losers,'daily' AS `type` 
      FROM historical_data 
      WHERE STR_TO_DATE(current_day, '%d-%M-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('14-DEC-2015', '%d-%M-%Y') 
      ORDER BY losers ASC 
      LIMIT 10 
     ) AS sub_daily;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4819/8)

**::OUTPUT::**

```
| symbol_name |              losers |  type |
|-------------|---------------------|-------|
|   ZYDUSWELL |  -7.600000000000023 | daily |
|       ZYLOG | -0.7600000000000002 | daily |
```

Comment: Or better yet, use DATE as the column type. And the quote columns should probably be numeric.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I also prefer DATE datatype is used for the date column.

Comment: @SaharshShah , thanks a lot , one  more query with this i can find top loosers of a day , similarly is it possible to find out top loosers for  the week based on the current data . please tell me how can i find that .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you created the field `current_day` as `VARCHAR` and it should be a `DATE`.

Also on your query you convert only the value to filter into a date and not the field itself.

So you should fix your table changing that field into a DATE of do this on your query `where` filter:

In the MySQL docs there is no `%MMM` format either change it to `%b` which is abbreviated month or `%M` month name the format parameter follows the `DATE_FORMAT` function format, see it here: [DATE_FORMAT Formats](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
select * 
  from (select symbol_name , 
               (prevclose_val-close_val) as losers, 
               'daily' as `type` 
          from historical_data 
         where STR_TO_DATE(current_day, '%d-%b-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('14-DEC-2015', '%d-%b-%Y')  
         order by losers asc limit 10 
       ) as sub_daily
```

If you convert the field into a DATE type you can do just:

```
select * 
  from (select symbol_name , 
               (prevclose_val-close_val) as losers, 
               'daily' as `type` 
          from historical_data 
         where current_day >= '2015-12-14'  
         order by losers asc limit 10 
       ) as sub_daily
```